# File size returned by DataTransferItem.getAsFile() is much larger than original file

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, copy-paste, clipboarddata

I have a png image file of size 1.8 MB.

While trying to copy paste the image file in chrome I am using DataTransferItem.getAsFile() method.
However the file object returned by the above call is of size ~11 MB.

Here is the code snippet:

```
items = clipboardItems.items;
item = this._getImageItem(items);
if(item) {
    file = item.getAsFile();
}
```

file.size > 11MB

Why is there such a huge difference in file size?

Is there any way I can retain the original (or near to original) file size?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the getAsFile() function returns a blob of an bitmap image.
See http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-March/030891.html for a discussion an that

Comment: The link is broken.